# SOLR currency FieldType

Tags: solr, currency

SOLR has a special type for currencies (CurrencyFieldType https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/currencies-exchange-rates.html).

I guess it supports sorting by values in one currency where prices in other currencies are converted on-the-fly. How it is implemented, what is its time complexity? Does it need to scan all prices, convert them and sort or it somehow use indexes per currency? Or maybe when the exchange rate change some indexes are recomputed (so exchange rates can't be changed every second)?

Answer (score 0):

The **currencyFieldType** is defined in `schema.xml`. This is the default configuration of this type and is implemented like this.

```
<fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyFieldType"
   amountLongSuffix="_l_ns" codeStrSuffix="_s_ns"
   defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml" 
/>
```

In this example, you notice that:

1. I have defined the **name** and **class** of the field type, and defined the **defaultCurrency** as "USD", for U.S. Dollars.
2. I have also defined a **currencyConfig** to use a file called "currency.xml". This is a file of exchange rates between our default currency to other currencies.
3. At indexing time, money fields can be indexed in a native currency.
   For example, if a product on an e-commerce site is listed in Euros, indexing the price field as "1000,EUR" will index it appropriately. The price should be separated from the currency by a comma, and the price must be encoded with a floating point value (a decimal point).

For more details on working with currencies and exchange rates, see the [link here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_1/working-with-currencies-and-exchange-rates.html#exchange-rates)